# Login page for Active Directory

Tags: ruby, windows, active-directory, saml, omniauth

**Requirement:** I've a Ruby on Rails application named as "RoR App", for instance. Several different clients have their own Active Directory and when a user hits a particular URL in the "RoR App" then the control will be redirected to the client's login page where user will provide their AD credentials.

Once authenticated, a callback will be called to the "RoR App" where a user's session be created.

**Work Done:** So far, I'm able to use [`omniauth-saml`](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth-saml) gem to redirect to some URL (will be client's login page later) when a user enters a particular URL in "RoR App" using SAML.

**Questions:**

For testing purpose, do I need to create a login page in some technology (RoR, PRP etc), which will work as client's (IDP) login page. And when the user provide their credentials then I've to write some code in backend to authenticate with active directory?

**OR**

Does AD or windows provides some self-managed login page which can be created (after some configuration) and performed authentication process itself?

*I'm new to Active Directory, so sorry it might be some obvious question.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Atlast, we've used Active Directory Federation Services (ADFS) for setting up the IDP which provides the login page and authenticate the user by using the configured user credentials in Active Directory.